# Moving from Grails searchable to Grails Elastic Search plugin

Tags: grails, elasticsearch, grails-plugin

In my project I am using the Grails Searchable plugin for caching and now I would like to move from that to the Grails Elastic Search plugin. It will be a big help if someone can guide me. The domain mapping conventions in Grails Elastic Search are not the same as in Grails Searchable (you can refer to [this link](http://grails.org/Searchable+Plugin+-+Mapping+-+Class+Mapping)). Any suggestions are greatly helpful.

Comment: What problem(s) are you facing?

Comment: Searchable mappings are different for elastic search plugin when we compare to searchable plugin am facing problems in converting.